# Updating one collection based on objectIDs from another collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The film collection has a review array of objects which holds the userid who made the review:[image]

The user collection has a filmsReviewed array of object storing all the films that user reviewed:
[image]

I want to delete a user which I know how to do but before I need to delete all the film reviews made by this user on films. I know how to perform the deletion of a review but don't know how to search for the films to be deleted within the films collection based on the filmReviewed array of objects in the User collection.

```
// search for all film reviews made by this user
//????????

// delete all film reviews made by this user for a specific film
await Film.findOneAndUpdate(
      {_id:request.params.filmid}, 
      {$pull:{reviews:{userid:mongoose.Types.ObjectId(request.body.userid)}}});

// delete the user
const opResult=await User.findByIdAndRemove(request.params.id);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to query the `user` collection and get the `_id` and `filmReviewed` values of the particular user.

Once you have this info, you now need to query `film` collection and find all the films where the above user left the reviews on (using `filmReviewed` array). You can use [$in](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#mongodb-query-op.-in) operator for this.

```
let filmsToUpdate = await Film.find( { _id : { $in : filmReviewed } } );
```

This will return all the movies where above user left the reviews on, then you can use `$pull` like you did in your question to update all the movies.

Finally once everything is deleted, delete the above user (you already have user's `_id`, we saved it above).

**EDIT**

In order to get `filmReviewed` array, you can just use `.findOne()` on user collection.

```
// This will return whole user object
let user = await user.findOne({ _id: request.params.id });

// Select filmsReviewed property from the above object
let filmReviewed = user.filmsReviewed;
```

Comment: "You first need to query the user collection and get the _id and filmReviewed values of the particular user" - this is what I don't know how to do. How to get an array of filmReviewed IDs for that particular user?

Answer (score 1):

Just do this,

*// Extract the list of films reviewed by this user.*

**const user = await User.findById(req.body.userid).select('filmsReviewed');**

*// This will return an object with String: _id and an Array: filmsReviewed*

*// Extract the films array*

**const filmsReviewed = user.filmsReviewed ;**

// Now use updateMany to update the films.

**await Film.updateMany({_id: req.params.filmid},  {$pull:{reviews:{userid:mongoose.Types.ObjectId(request.body.userid)}}});**

// And finally delete the user

**await User.findByIdAndRemove(request.params.userid);**